# How can I extend a chart in Excel by a certain amount of months including named ranges?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to extend all charts in a sheet by 12 months to add another year on a monthly line graph. This is what I have so far.

```
Sub Chart_Extender()

Dim Rng_Extension As Integer
Dim Series_Formula As String
Dim StartPoint As String
Dim EndPoint As String
Dim CommaSplit As Variant
Dim ColonSplit As Variant
Dim grph As ChartObject
Dim ser As Series


'Determine the length of the extension (in cells)
 On Error GoTo BadEntry
    Rng_Extension = InputBox( _
  "How many cells do you want to extend your chart's series?", _
  "Chart Extender")
   On Error GoTo 0

    For Each grph In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    For Each ser In grph.Chart.SeriesCollection

        Series_Formula = ser.Formula


        CommaSplit = Split(Series_Formula, ",") 

        ColonSplit = Split(CommaSplit(2), ":")  

        StartPoint = ColonSplit(0)  

        EndPoint = ColonSplit(1)   

        EndPoint = Range(EndPoint).Offset(0, Rng_Extension).Address 

        ser.Values = StartPoint & ":" & EndPoint 'Combine Start and End Point & Set Series = To It        

        If CommaSplit(1) <> "" Then
          ColonSplit = Split(CommaSplit(1), ":")               
          StartPoint = ColonSplit(0)                
          EndPoint = ColonSplit(1)                  
          EndPoint = Range(EndPoint).Offset(0, Rng_Extension).Address  'Extended Ending Point Range    
          ser.XValues = StartPoint & ":" & EndPoint 'Combine Start and End Point & Set Series = To It
        End If
    End If
Next ser
Next grph
MsgBox "Your chart has been Extended by " & Rng_Extension & " positions."
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

However, since there are named ranges in the graphs as well it seems to get stuck and has an error at EndPoint=ColonSplit(1) saying "Subscript out of range". Is there a way to fix this? Also is there a way to add another loop to have this go through each sheet in the workbook and extend all of them?

Comment: That would mean that `ColonSplit(1)` doesn't have a value. When it errors out, and you click "Debug", hover your mouse over that variable, and it should show you what is stored there. Or in the Immediate Window (press CTRL+G in VBE), type `?ColonSplit(1)` and see if it returns the error, or a value.

Comment: You are also presuming that: **1**. User will always provide a value. **2**. User will not press `Cancel`. **3**. User input will always be valid. I would validate the input before entering any of the `FOR` loops

Answer (score 0):

After you have validated user input and are sure that you do need to extend the charts, create a workbook and worksheet object:

```
Dim oWB As Workbook: Set oWB = ThisWorkbook
Dim oWS As Worksheet
```

Now add the following loop before any of your `FOR` loops:

```
For Each oWS In oWB.Worksheets
    ' Your FOR loops here
Next
```

This will go through all the sheets in your workbook. 
**NOTE**: Don't forget to add `oWS` before you reference a `Range` or `Cell`